# email with company domain

Tags: excel, vba, email

I'm trying to create a VBA script which uses the Google server but company domain. A typical example would be `firstname@company.com`.

I'm using the code below but it gives me an error if I use a domain name that's not `gmail`. I want to ask the user to enter their login information (username and password).

```
Sub SendGMail()

' Object creation
Set objMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set msgConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

' Server Configuration
msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value
msgConf.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
msgConf.Fields.Update

' Email
objMsg.To = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
objMsg.From = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
objMsg.Subject = "Test send with Gmail account"
objMsg.HTMLBody = "HTML/Plain text message."
objMsg.Sender = "Mr. Name"

Set objMsg.Configuration = msgConf

' Send
objMsg.Send

' Clear
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set msgConf = Nothing 

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add Microsoft CDO Reference before running the code

Tool-->Reference---> Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library

```
Sub MailTest()

Dim Mail As New Message
Dim Config As Configuration

Set Config = Mail.Configuration

Config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
Config(cdoSMTPServer) = "smtp.gmail.com"
Config(cdoSMTPServerPort) = 25
Config(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
Config(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = True
Config(cdoSendUserName) = InputBox("EnterUsername")
' Otherwise if you use text box
'config(cdoSendUserName) = UserForm1.TextBox1.Text
Config(cdoSendPassword) = InputBox("Password")
' Otherwise if you use text box
'config(cdoSendUserName) = UserForm1.TextBox2.Text
Config.Fields.Update


Mail.To = "yahoo44@gmail.com"
Mail.From = Config(cdoSendUserName)
Mail.Subject = "Email Subject"
Mail.HTMLBody = "<b> mail body </b>"
Mail.Sender = " MRSender"

  Mail.Send
  MsgBox "mail has been sent"

End Sub
```

Comment: May i knew why down vote my answer even after i provided valid answer?